# Parse JSON into array javascript with Twilio Function

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

Attempting to create a chat bot that will hit a web service midway through and ask questions based on previous responses.

I have created a function that will return an array of people that I will then text these names and ask the user to pick one.

**Twilio Function**

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
 const employees = [{  name: 'Mark', id:15 }, {  name: 'Scott', id:16 }, {  name: 'Steve', id:17 }];
 callback(null, employees);
};
```

I would hope this would return function_1.parsed values, but everything is stored in function_1.body and I can't access it the way I hoped.

Here's a view of my Log.

[image]

Anyone know how I can send this to Parsed instead of body? If I submit a simple object it will return to the parsed value.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
 const employee = {  name: 'Mark', id:15 };
 callback(null, employee);
};
```

[image]

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/run-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the trick, Wrap it in an object:

```
{"result":
   [{  name: 'Mark', id:15 }, {  name: 'Scott', id:16 }, {  name: 'Steve', id:17 }]
};
```